# Watson assistant API calls is working in cURL and not through browse

Tags: watson-assistant

I was trying to access watson assistant API. I tried the following methods.
 1. cURL
curl -X POST -u "apikey:Gylnwp*******************Pnbxlf" --header "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Hi\"}}" https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/f2b4**********de0a3/message?version=2018-09-20

I got the exact output with the response from the assistant

2. Browser
   https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api/v1/workspaces/f2b45****************de0a3/message?version=2018-09-20
   I gave the following link in the browser to check whether it is working well. I got an error 404:Resource not found.
   {"error":"Resource not found","code":404}
   Can someone guide me to solve this. I am a starter in Watson. Please let me know if I had done something wrong.
   Best Regards
   Anila

Comment: How do you perform authentication in your browser test? For browser testing use something like postman

Comment: Yes, I was using Postman and authenticated username: apikey and password: Gylnwp*******************Pnbxlf.

Comment: I even tried using apikey:Gylnwp*******************Pnbxlf but then I am getting 401 error unauthorized

Comment: Hi - the basics of what you are trying look correct ( see the watson doc's https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant#get-response-to-user-input

I would double check your api url (is your workspace in the London centre ) and that you have included \" around the url (not shown above). And then your api password. 
The error is normally an indication that the gateway cannot match your request to a workspace. It would come back with authentication error is it was just a password issue.